# Is passing a new string to a function already allocating memory (without using that string)?

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine, allocation

We're coding in Unity but I guess it also applies to standard C# apps.

We're trying to avoid creating strings in live builds to prevent garbage collection.

If I understand strings correctly, if I create a new string `"ABC"` it will allocate memory for the first time but then it will be cached (this exact string) and it shouldn't allocate memory if we reuse that string. I know that there is more to it and the caching mechanisms are much more complex than that.

But I was wondering about function arguments. Let's say we call a function and pass directly created string to it:

```
fun("ABC");
```

I guess the rules still apply: `"ABC"` will allocate memory with the first invocation of `fun()` but subsequent calls will not allocate (because of caching)

What bothers me is lots of optimization guides suggesting that we should use compilation directives to remove logs from live builds like this (example [here](https://gamedevbeginner.com/how-to-use-debug-log-in-unity-without-affecting-performance/)):

```
public static void LogMessage(string message)
{
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    Debug.Log(message);
    #endif
}
```

If the `UNITY_EDITOR` directive is `false` it's obviously gonna strip the debug log from the final build, but the invocation will still remain in the code:

```
LogMessage("some message");
```

Which - if I'm not wrong - will still allocate memory on the first invocation.

Or maybe, if the compilator detects that this string is indeed passed to the function but it's not used later, it will not allocate? How does it work?

Comment: String literals are usually allocated in some "read-only" memory on program startup, not when they are first used

Comment: FYI: "_If I understand strings correctly, if I create a new string "ABC" it will allocate memory for the first time but then it will be cached (this exact string) and it shouldn't allocate memory if we reuse that string._" This is ambiguous and therefore technically not completely true, as there are [public string constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-7.0#constructors) that create new strings but which are not interned (cached)...

Comment: All string literals are interned at compile time, so the constant `"ABC"` results in no allocation. There is no "caching" of strings, however -- `Object.ReferenceEquals(new string("ABC"), new string("ABC"))` is `false` since these really are different strings. You can intern strings yourself, but this should not be considered "caching", as its purpose is different, and it's only rarely useful to do explicitly.

Comment: FYI if you want to optimize such functions, use [ConditionalAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute?view=net-7.0)

Comment: What if I create a string like `fun("ABC" + (i++));` ? This cannot be interned at compile time. Is such string cached later? ("ABC1", "ABC2")?

Comment: `"ABC"` is a string literal and it will be interned. The expression `"ABC" + (i++)` isn't a literal and will result in creating a string at runtime. Again, there is no caching, and if you don't call `.Intern()`, there is no interning either. Embedding an expression with a side effect into a logging message is, of course, bad practice; if you instead did `i++; Logger.LogInfo("ABC{i}", i)`, creation of a string at runtime would be elided if logging was disabled (most logging frameworks adopt string templates or format strings for exactly this purpose).